# how to save the name of a file in mysql using plupload

Tags: php, mysql, plupload

I wonder how I do to save the name of an `image` in `mysql` with `plupload`?

In file `upload.php` have many variables and I do not know which one stores the `filename`, already tried everything and could not
I would like to save the `image name` that `plupload` creates, not the `original name`
can someone help me?

thank you

Comment: please show some code

Comment: Please show upload.php code

Comment: my code like this https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/upload.php

Answer (score 0):

Get the file name like this.

```
$filename = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

and pass $filename into insert statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this plugin for [plupload](https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload/blob/master/examples/upload.php) to `upload file` from github

Answer (score 0):

You can directly used a $fileName variable
here give you a example, like
$sSQL = "INSERT INTO eletz_multiimage (image_name) VALUES ('$fileName')";
$result = mysql_query($sSQL);